# failed to StartActivity in Class extends From BaseAdapter in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

i am trying to customize listview which is working fine and now i have made customclass extends from baseAdapter in this part getView method i am applying **onclickListener** in imageview and starting new Activity this is crashing app
 **code**

```
 public class CustomAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter
{
ArrayList<FatwaBean> fatwaArrayList;
Context context;

CustomAdapterClass(ArrayList<FatwaBean> data,Context c) {
    fatwaArrayList = data;
    context = c;
}
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return fatwaArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return fatwaArrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     View v = convertView;
     if (v == null)
     {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.search_fatwa_row, null);
     }

      final ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.search_image_row);
       TextView dateTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.search_date_row);

       FatwaBean fatwaBean= fatwaArrayList.get(position);
     //image.setImageResource(fatwaBean.getQuestionImage());
       image.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_icon);
      //image.setTag(fatwaBean.getFatwaTopicQuestionId());
       dateTextView.setText(fatwaBean.getFatwaDate());
       Log.i("fatwaBean",""+fatwaBean.getFatwaDate());
       Log.i("fatwaBean",""+fatwaBean.getFatwaImageName());
       Log.i("fatwaBean Topic Question Image Name",""+fatwaBean.getQuestionImage());

       image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              
               public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub


               final int itemname= (int)fatwaArrayList.get(position).getFatwaTopicQuestionId();
               Log.i("clicked Fatwa Image Topic Id",""+fatwaArrayList.get(position).getFatwaTopicQuestionId());
               Intent intent = new Intent(context,FatwaZoomActivityImageView.class);
           //passing fatwa topic question Id to get FatwaImage in NextActivity

              intent.putExtra("questionTopicIdForFatwa",fatwaArrayList.get(position).getFatwaTopicQuestionId());
              intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
               context.startActivity(intent);

           }                        
       });
    return v;
}
```

**Logcat**:

```
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:803)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at com.jamia.binoria.CustomAdapterClass$1.onClick(CustomAdapterClass.java:73)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-19 22:02:05.220: E/AndroidRuntime(578):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How do you initialize the context in your adapter class?

Comment: have you tried using
Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),FatwaZoomActivityImageView.class);

Comment: @Merlevede i am calling adapter class from activity from there i am passing context and initializing it in adapter class

Comment: @soynerdito  yes have tried same error

Answer (score 1):

Add this before the startActivity(), as suggested in the LogCat.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

The logcat message seems pretty straightforward to me:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

If you don't want to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, then your Adapter should probably call back to your main Activity or Fragment to start the next Activity.

Since you are calling `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);`, I'm guessing that you don't really want the new task flag, and calling back to the parent Activity/Fragment is your best option.

Comment: please mention whats the solution ?

Comment: I did. If you don't need `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`, then you can replace that flag with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. If you need the multiple task flag, then your adapter will need to call back to your Activity (through an interface or a public method in the Activity), which should then start the next Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should be a comment but it's a little long, so...

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Context has a StartActivity method, and so does Activity. Your `context` variable is of type Context, which points to an Activity object, but I don't know if the method being invoked belongs to the Context or to the Activity object.

Maybe you could try replacing your member variable `Context context` with `Activity parentActivity`??

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` you passed to the `CustomAdapterClass` constructor was not an `Activity` context but something different, possibly an `Application`. Hence the exception. Read [this article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) for more explanation what different `Context`s are good for.

Two solutions:

1. Pass in an `Activity` context. This should be the preferred option.
2. Add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` as suggested by some other answers. Note that doing so has implications to how activity back stack navigation works and it's not necessarily something you want.